# how to collect multiple dataset data into one dataset?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset

I need to show multiple records together in a gridview in c# with SQL.

i have an array of Id's using those id's i need to get all details correspond to those id's.

i have an array `ID[]` `Dataset ds`

```
for(int i=0; i<=ID.Length-1; i++)
{
   dss = fill_DS("select Client_id, F_name, L_name, Ph, Alt_ph, Time_date, Plan_duration, Brand, Email from Client_detail where Client_id='" + ID[i]+ "'");
}
```

Second method

```
public static DataSet fill_DS(string query)
{
    DataSet ds=null; 
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return ds;
}
```

It only returns me the result of the last row only or for last id only. i need to combine the rows for all id's and show them in a gridview.

How to do this?

Comment: Here is a chapter for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984388(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: i do have tried this but not working for me.

Comment: some error occurred which led to page response failure it gives me error 500

Comment: Debug into `fill_DS` and find the exact query you're executing, then execute it in SSMS and see how many rows are returned.

Comment: @NeelBhasin: then use the debugger and see what happens, what error do you get and where exactly. You can also inspect the values of all variables or look at the `DataTable(s)` inside of the `DataSet(s)`.

Comment: actually i am working on remote location all work is online that's the reason i am not able to use debugger

Comment: You could also change the query to use `where Client_id IN (`?

Comment: @NickyvV can u explain me how to pass complete array into it

Comment: Get a comma separated list of the ID's and put that between the parenthesis. Something like this: `where Client_id IN (" + IDs + ")"`